# Programa para realizar WireFrame

Tags: android

Sabeis de algun programa capaz de realizar el entramado de actividades y métodos de una aplicación. Creo que la palabra técnica es Wireframe. Pero mas que nada por lo leído en algun post. Lo que trato de realizar es lo siguiente:

[image: Situacion]

Comment: [Balsamiq Mockups | Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/) o https://moqups.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo soy desarrollador webApps, y generalmente uso Balsamiq Mockups, el programa es practico, facil de usar y tiene un estilo amigable, y contiene templates para web y movil, espero que sea de tu ayuda.